# mod_rewrite, i want to rewrite: index.php?page=contact to contact

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want people using my site to see site.com/contact in the browser address bar in place of site.com/index.php?page=contact.

I'm new to mod_rewrite, and so far, I came to this rule.

The code I have right now is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1
```

How would I accomplish this?

EDIT:
The problem is that the URL of my contact page still says: site.com/index.php?page=contact.

Comment: Tell us what doesn't work and what you've tried.

Comment: i'm sorry; when i go to my contact page the URL  still says: index.php?page=contact

Answer (score 0):

The last part, the RewriteRule, should look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(contact)/?$ index.php?page=$1
```

That means if the user types, "mysite.com/contact" they're actually being served up "mysite.com/index.php?page=contact".

The parentheses create the capture group, which translates to `$1`. For each consecutive parentheses, the capture group variable increments - `$2`, `$3`, and so on.